# "could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name or service not known" With Postgres in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to have one docker container talk to Postgres in another container using docker compose.

Here is my compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    restart: always
    build: cloudpebble/
    ports:
      - "8090:8090"
    volumes:
      - "./cloudpebble/:/code"
    links:
      - redis
      - postgres:postgres
      - s3
      - qemu
      - ycmd
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - DEBUG="yes"
      - RUN_WEB="yes"
      - AWS_ENABLED="yes"
      - PORT=8090
      - AWS_S3_FAKE_S3=10.0.0.4:8003
      - MEDIA_URL=http://10.0.0.4:8003/builds.cloudpebble.net/
      - QEMU_URLS=http://10.0.0.4:8001/
      - YCM_URLS=http://10.0.0.4:8002/
      - PUBLIC_URL=http://10.0.0.4:8090/
      - LIBPEBBLE_PROXY=wss://cloudpebble-ws.herokuapp.com/tool
      - PEBBLE_AUTH_URL=https://auth.rebble.io
    networks:
      - dbnet
  celery:
    build: cloudpebble/
    volumes:
      - "./cloudpebble/:/code"
    links:
      - redis
      - postgres
      - s3
    environment:
      - DEBUG="yes"
      - RUN_CELERY="yes"
      - AWS_ENABLED=yes
      - EXPORT_ROOT=http://10.0.0.4/export.cloudpebble.net/
      - AWS_S3_FAKE_S3=10.0.0.4:8003
  qemu:
    build: cloudpebble-qemu-controller/
    volumes:
      - "./cloudpebble-qemu-controller/:/code"
    ports:
      - "8001:80"
  ycmd:
    build: cloudpebble-ycmd-proxy/
    volumes:
      - "./cloudpebble-ycmd-proxy/:/code"
    ports:
      - "8002:80"
  redis:
    image: redis
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - dbnet
    container_name: postgres
  s3:
    image: kuracloud/fake-s3
    ports:
      - "8003:4569"
networks:
  default:
    name: pebble
  dbnet:
    driver: bridge
```

The problem is, even though both networks are created, the 'web' container can't see Postgres and gives me this error: `could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name or service not known`

Thank you!

I have tried the following:

- Upgrading to compose v2
- Using a separate network
- Using links
- Starting Postgres first then starting `web`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two separate networks, but that doesn't seem necessary.  The database container is on its own isolated `dbnet`, but none of the other containers are.  For two containers to connect, either neither container may have a `networks:` block, or both do and contain at least one network name in common, or only one does but it explicitly contains `default`.

The easiest solution here is just to use the Compose-provided `default` network for everything.  Delete *all* of the `networks:` blocks in the entire file.  The `links:` options are obsolete and the archaic network mode it activates can occasionally cause problems; delete these (or possibly change them to `depends_on:).

Comment: Okay, did that. However, I still get the same error. This time, it did say it created the default network. I also changed all the links to depends_on.

Comment: Ah! Just fixed this. Turns out, the environment variable for the DB password was not getting set properly. Thank you!